# How to handle conditions after asynchronous request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, es6-promise, antd-mobile

Thanks for reading my question in advance. I'm using the [dva](https://github.com/dvajs/dva/blob/master/README.md) and [Ant Design Mobile of React](https://mobile.ant.design/docs/react/introduce-cn)  handling phone register function.

Before sending the verify code, I will judge if the phone has been registered. If yes, it will Toast " This phone has been registered".

Now, the return value is correct:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state.register.message)
}
// {code: 221, message: "This phone has been registered"}
```

So I write it as:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  returnData: state.register.message
})
```

And then when I click the button, it will dispatch an action (send a request):

```
  getVerifyCode() {
    const { form, returnData } = this.props;
    const { getFieldsValue } = form;
    const values = getFieldsValue();
    this.props.dispatcher.register.send({
        phone: values.phone,
        purpose: 'register',
      })
      // if(returnData.code === 221){
      //   Toast.fail("This phone has been registered", 1);
      // } else {
      //   Toast.success("Send verify code successfully", 1);
      // }
  }
```

But when I tried to add the if...else condiction according to the return value

```
   if(returnData.code === 221){
     Toast.fail("This phone has been registered", 1);
   } else {
     Toast.success("Send verify code successfully", 1);
   }
```

only to get the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of
>   undefined

I supposed it's the problem about aynchromous and tried to use async await:

```
  async getVerifyCode() {
    ...
    await this.props.dispatcher.register.send({
        phone: values.phone,
        purpose: 'register',
      })
  }
```

But get the same error

> Cannot read property 'code' of undefined

I wonder why and how to fix this problem ?

added: this is the models

```
import * as regiserService from '../services/register';

export default {
  namespace: 'register',
  state: {},
  subscriptions: {
  },
  reducers: {
    save(state, { payload: { data: message, code } }) {
      return { ...state, message, code };
    },
  },
  effects: {
    *send({ payload }, { call, put }) {
      const { data } = yield call(regiserService.sendAuthCode, { ...payload });
      const message = data.message;
      yield put({ type: 'save', payload: { data },});
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Please add the reducer code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

handle conditions in the models solved the problem:

```
*send({ payload }, { call, put }) {
  const { data } = yield call(regiserService.sendAuthCode, { ...payload });
  if(data.code === 221){
    Toast.fail("This phone has been registered", 1);
  } else {
    Toast.success("Send verify code successfully", 1);
  }
    yield put({ type: 'save', payload: { data }});
  }
```